# Maximum Path Sum between 2 Leaf Nodes(GeeksForGeeks)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, tree

Given a binary tree in which each node element contains a number. Find the maximum possible sum from one leaf node to another.

Example 1:

```
Input :      
           3                               
         /    \                          
       4       5                     
      /  \      
    -10   4                          

Output: 16
```

Explanation :
Maximum Sum lies between leaf node 4 and 5.
4 + 4 + 3 + 5 = 16.

Example 2:

```
Input :    
            -15                               
         /      \                          
        5         6                      
      /  \       / \
    -8    1     3   9
   /  \              \
  2   -3              0
                     / \
                    4  -1
                       /
                     10  

Output :  27
```

Explanation:
The maximum possible sum from one leaf node
to another is (3 + 6 + 9 + 0 + -1 + 10 = 27)

This is the solution:

```
'''
# Node Class:
class Node:
    def _init_(self,val):
        self.data = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        '''
res = -999999999
def maxPathSumUtil(root):
    global res
    if root is None:
        return 0
    
    if root.left is None and root.right is None:
        return root.data

    ls=maxPathSumUtil(root.left)
    rs=maxPathSumUtil(root.right)
    
    if root.left and root.right:
        res=max(res,ls+rs+root.data)
        return max(ls+root.data,rs+root.data) #Line: Problem
    if root.left is None:
        return rs+root.data
    else:
        return ls+root.data


def maxPathSum(root):
    global res
    res = -999999999
    maxPathSumUtil(root)
    return res
```

Can anyone tell me why do we use `return max(ls+root.data,rs+root.data)`. And if we do use `return max(ls+root.data,rs+root.data)` for checking the maximum value then why do we use `res=max(res,ls+rs+root.data)` and not just  `res = max(ls+root.data,rs+root.data)`.

EDIT:

For example:

```
Let's take this tree for example:

             10
           /   \
         8      2
       /  \
     3     5
```

In this, after recursive calls, `ls` becomes 3 and `rs` becomes 5.
`res` becomes `ls+rs+root.data` which is 3+5+8 = 16.
Then `return max(ls+root.data,rs+root.data)` which is max(11,13) = 13.
Now after this according to me the function should just return 13 but that does not happen. Even though `return` is not a recursive statement. How is the control flow of the code happening?

Comment: Path between 2 leaf nodes also involves root node. Note that root can also be a subroot of a subtree and not necessarily pass through actual root of the tree.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that are measured in parallel during execution:

- `ls+rs+root.data` is the max path in the tree rooted by `root`, between two of the leaves below it. So it is (the value) of a **leaf**-to-leaf path
- The function return value is the maximum path from `root` to any of the leaves below it. So it is (the value) of a **root**-to-leaf path

These are two different concepts and should not be mixed up.

Both `ls` and `rs` are function return values: `ls` represents the maximum path from `root.left` to a leaf. And in the same way `rs` represents the maximum path from `root.right` to a leaf.

`ls+rs+root.data` on the other hand, represents a path from leaf to leaf passing through `root`.

`res` should be updated if that latter expression is greater than `res`, hence the `max()`.

But the function's return value should not represent a leaf-to-leaf path, but a root-to-leaf path. So that is why we have:

```
return max(ls+root.data,rs+root.data)
```

This tells the caller what the maximum root-to-leaf path is, not what the maximum leaf-to-leaf path is. The latter is used for determining `res`, not the function's return value.

I hope this clarifies the distinction between these two concepts and the roles they play in the algorithm.

### The example

You presented this tree as example:

```
         10
       /   \
     8      2
   /  \
 3     5
```

Indeed, when the function is called for the node 8, it:

- sets `res` to 16 (the max path between two leaves below the node)
- returns 13 (the max path from the node to one of its leaves)

You then ask:

> Now after this according to me the function should just return 13 but that does not happen.

But it *does* happen like that. You should however not forget that this is the return value of `maxPathSumUtil`, not of `maxPathSum`. Also, this is not the top-level call of `maxPathSumUtil`. The value 13 is returned to another execution context of `maxPathSumUtil`, where `root` is the node 10. Then -- after another recursive call is made (with `root` equal to node 2), this top-level execution of the function `maxPathSumUtil` will:

- set `res` to 25 (the max path between two leaves below the node 10)
- return 23 (the max path from the node 10 to one of its leaves)

This toplevel call was made from within `maxPathSum`, which *ignores* the value returned by `maxPathSumUntil`.
It only takes the value of `res` (25), and returns *that*:

```
maxPathSumUtil(root)  # notice that return value is ignored.
return res
```

Comment: Thanks sir, could you please tell me how the ```Line: Problem``` is working, since after recursive statement is executed the return statement is also executed

Comment: Yes, what exactly is the problem with that?

Comment: Sir, I have edited my question. Kindly have a look.

Comment: See addition to my answer.

Comment: So, does that mean that when 13 is returned and the function moves to the top level call,
```ls``` becomes 13 and hence due to that ```res``` becomes ```ls+rs+root.data``` which is equal to 13+2+10 = 25. If so, then how is ```ls``` becoming 13 as we are not explicitly saying that ```ls``` = ```max(ls+root.data,rs+root.data)```.
P.S: Sorry for bothering

Comment: `ls` becomes thirteen in the execution context where `root` is 10. This happens when coming back from the deeper call on node 8: `ls=maxPathSumUtil(root.left)`. And of course that function call returns via `return ...`, so that is how `ls` gets that returned value.

Comment: Thank you God(trincot) for everything!

Answer (score 0):

At each node, we have to check whether that node's left and right child resulted in max path. But when we return, we need to return either the left or right path depending upon whichever is max.
Let's take this tree for example:

```
         10
       /   \
     8      2
   /  \
 3     5
```

In this, after recursive calls, ls becomes 3 and rs becomes 5. res becomes ls+rs+root.data which is 3+5+8 = 16. So res(result) will be updated to 16, and return will be max(11,13) which is 13. **Now this 13 value will be used by node 10 as ls(left value).**